# Limit query result per unique columns combination

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I would like to modify this query to limit result to have max 2 rows (latest) per group:

```
select
    distinct clusterName,
    aksNamespace,
    acrName,
    acrImageName,
    acrImageVersion,
    date
from
    (
    select
        clusterName,
        aksNamespace,
        acrName,
        acrImageName,
        acrImageVersion,
        date
    from
        aks_images
    order by
        acrImageName,
        date desc
) as t
where
    acrName = "storage"
order by
    clusterName,
    acrImageName,
    date desc
```

*Current result*:

| clusterName | aksNamespace | acrName | acrImageName | acrImageVersion | `date` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| dev | support | storage | app | f74581b | 17.02.2023 14:35 |
| dev | support | storage | app | c6040a0 | 17.02.2023 7:45 |
| dev | support | storage | app | 4410f39 | 16.02.2023 10:43 |
| dev | abc | storage | qwer | 93241f1 | 15.02.2023 12:45 |
| dev | abc | storage | qwer | 249b089 | 14.02.2023 13:15 |
| dev | abc | storage | qwer | 1c40785 | 13.02.2023 13:30 |
| prod | support | storage | app | 469a492 | 07.02.2023 14:15 |
| test | support | storage | app | 07e22a6 | 17.02.2023 14:40 |
| test | support | storage | app | daf975d | 17.02.2023 13:40 |
| test | support | storage | app | 7e1a50b | 15.02.2023 13:10 |
| test | support | storage | app | 8f27715 | 15.02.2023 9:35 |

*Expected result*:

| clusterName | aksNamespace | acrName | acrImageName | acrImageVersion | `date` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| dev | support | storage | app | f74581b | 17.02.2023 14:35 |
| dev | support | storage | app | c6040a0 | 17.02.2023 7:45 |
| dev | abc | storage | qwer | 93241f1 | 15.02.2023 12:45 |
| dev | abc | storage | qwer | 249b089 | 14.02.2023 13:15 |
| prod | support | storage | app | 469a492 | 07.02.2023 14:15 |
| test | support | storage | app | 07e22a6 | 17.02.2023 14:40 |
| test | support | storage | app | daf975d | 17.02.2023 13:40 |

**Mysql version**: 8.0.31

I'd be grateful for any advice or solutions.

Comment: SELECT
  clusterName,
  aksNamespace,
  acrName,
  acrImageName,
  acrImageVersion,
  date
FROM (
  SELECT
    clusterName,
    aksNamespace,
    acrName,
    acrImageName,
    acrImageVersion,
    date,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY clusterName, acrImageName ORDER BY date DESC) AS rn
  FROM aks_images
  WHERE acrName = "storage"
) AS t
WHERE rn <= 2
ORDER BY clusterName, acrImageName, date DESC;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On MySQL 8+, we can use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY clusterName, acrImageName
                                 ORDER BY date DESC) rn
    FROM aks_images
    WHERE acrName = 'storage'
)

SELECT
    clusterName,
    aksNamespace,
    acrName,
    acrImageName,
    acrImageVersion,
    date
FROM cte
WHERE rn <= 2
ORDER BY
    clusterName,
    acrImageName,
    date DESC;
```

Comment: Hi Tim,  I'm sure it was easy for you, but for me it's a huuuuge help. Thank you very much for your time and help!